# Using wokerpool on multi node.js processes running on the same server

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, load-balancing, worker-thread

I have a server with 6 CPU logical cores, there is 6 node.js (v 16) processes running express.js app within the server and managed by pm2 process manager, and I'm using Nginx proxy to load balance the traffic between the processes.
Nginx configuration:

```
upstream nodes {
   ip_hash;
   server localhost:3001;
   server localhost:3002;
   server localhost:3003;
   server localhost:3004;
   server localhost:3005;
   server localhost:3006;
}

server {
  server_name SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;
      location / {
        proxy_pass          http://nodes;
    }
}
```

I have a CPU intensive task and I want to offload it on a worker thread using [workerpool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool) package, and it'll create worker threads corresponds to the number of CPU cores, so 6 thread for each node.js process, which mean 36 worker thread in total.

Is it good to have 36 node.js worker threads on 6 CPU cores? will CPU scheduling time affect app performance?